# Java (JRE 1.8.0_141) - Error 405 for GET request

Tags: java, http-status-code-405

I am using Java JRE 1.8.0_141 and I am trying to access a specific URL and store the HTML into a String so that I can manipulate the data later in the code, but I keep getting error 405 whenever I call getInputStream().

The code seems to work with other URLs without problems. The trouble URL is:

http://www.streeteasy.com/for-rent/nyc/status:open%7Cprice:1750-2900%7Carea:104,116,119,143,141%7Camenities:pool?page=2&refined_search=true

Here is Eclipse 4.6.3's specific error:

```
<terminated, exit value: 1>C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_141\bin\javaw.exe (Aug 6, 2017, 10:53:37 PM)  

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: http://www.streeteasy.com/for-rent/nyc/status:open%7Cprice:1750-2900%7Carea:104,116,119,143,141%7Camenities:pool?page=2&refined_search=true
    at RunMe.getHTMLFromURL(RunMe.java:52)
    at RunMe.main(RunMe.java:18)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: http://www.streeteasy.com/for-rent/nyc/status:open%7Cprice:1750-2900%7Carea:104,116,119,143,141%7Camenities:pool?page=2&refined_search=true
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at RunMe.getHTMLFromURL(RunMe.java:36)
    ... 1 more
```

My RunMe.java code is below:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class RunMe {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println(getHTMLFromURL("http://www.streeteasy.com/for-rent/nyc/status:open%7Cprice:1750-2900%7Carea:104,116,119,143,141%7Camenities:pool?page=2&refined_search=true"));      
}

public static String getHTMLFromURL(String url){
        try{
            URL urlObj = new URL(url);
            URLConnection con = urlObj.openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(false);
            con.connect();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream())); 
            // CODE FAILS HERE ^

            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            String inputLine;

            String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                response.append(inputLine + newLine);
            }
            in.close();

            return response.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how I can pull the HTML from this URL if not via this method? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the problem is the header, try put this headers: 'User-Agent': 'request',
        'Accept': 'text/html;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'

Comment: Not sure how to do that! Any advice?
If it helps, System.out.println(con.getHeaderFields()) gives me:

{Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], null=[HTTP/1.1 405 Not Allowed], X-DZ=[50.4.77.193], Cache-Control=[private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate], Server=[nginx], Edge-Control=[no-store, bypass-cache], Connection=[keep-alive], Surrogate-Control=[no-store, bypass-cache], Expires=[Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT], Date=[Mon, 07 Aug 2017 03:55:51 GMT], Content-Type=[text/html]}

Comment: Did you send the headers as I mentioned.

Comment: @FadySaad I don't think that's the issue here, see my answer.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. I do not understand how to follow your instructions. What specific code edits are you proposing?

Answer (score -1):

I executed a `curl` command against the URL and it seems like the site is trying to run JavaScript for rendering the page.

```
curl -v -L -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0" -H "Accept: text/html" "http://www.streeteasy.com/for-rent/nyc/status:open%7Cprice:1750-2900%7Carea:104,116,119,143,141%7Camenities:pool?page=2"

> GET /for-rent/nyc/status:open%7Cprice:1750-2900%7Carea:104,116,119,143,141%7Camenities:pool?page=2 HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.streeteasy.com
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
> Accept: text/html
> 
< HTTP/1.1 405 Not Allowed

// elided

<h1>Pardon Our Interruption...</h1>
<p>As you were browsing <strong>www.streeteasy.com</strong> something about your browser made us think you were a bot. There are a few reasons this might happen:</p>
<ul>
    <li>You're a power user moving through this website with super-human speed.</li>
    <li>You've disabled JavaScript in your web browser.</li>
    <li>A third-party browser plugin, such as Ghostery or NoScript, is preventing JavaScript from running. Additional information is available in this <a title='Third party browser plugins that block javascript' href='http://ds.tl/help-third-party-plugins' target='_blank'>support article</a>.</li>
</ul>

<p>After completing the CAPTCHA below, you will immediately regain access to www.streeteasy.com.</p>
```

You may be outta luck here unless you can programmatically fill in the captcha.

**Edit**:

The problem is clearly cookies as indicated in the discussion below.

Comment: If it helps, I am able to browse the website on Chrome/Firefox with JavaScript disabled. Alternatively, would it be possible to use Java to indirectly read the file, perhaps by downloading the rendered HTML, reading that source, then deleting the file?

Comment: @sweebez I don't know what you mean by "use Java to indirectly read the file". There is no file on your client; if the server refuses to respond, there's nothing you can do other than politely ask them. client-server 101. I suggest you try to figure out what headers your browser is sending with the request.

Comment: I guess I am confused why Java is unable to access the website, while my browsers (with JS disabled) have no trouble doing so.

Comment: @sweebez Because, the Java client is not a browser. Try from a browser with cookies disabled, which is think is the issue.

Comment: I think you are correct -- when cookies are disabled, the "Pardon Our Interruption" page is triggered. Is that a terminal diagnosis?

Comment: @sweebez I don't understand what is a "terminal diagnosis" in terms of this problem; we are not the Cancer Treatment Centers of America. You know the problem now, feel free to look into it. If my answer helped you, consider upvoting and/or accepting it.